# Every Countable Model of PA is Recursive?

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

I am interested in any obvious flaws in the following argument.

Assume we have a countable model of [Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) in a meta-theory like ZFC. Assume this model has a set of ordered triplets, $\mathbb{A}$, that defines addition. $\mathbb{A}$ is countable because the model is countable. Assume we have a bijection between $\mathbb{A}$ and the standard natural numbers, $\aleph_0$. Using this bijection, we can index each element, $a_i \in \mathbb{A}$, with a standard natural number. We now have an indexed set of ordered triplets, $[a_i, b_i, c_i]$ such that $a_i + b_i = c_i$.

Define the function $ADD(x,y)$. This function searches $\mathbb{A}$ in index order until it finds $a_i = x$ and $b_i=y$. It then returns $c_i$. Clearly, $ADD(x,y)$ finds $c_i$ in a finite number of steps. This proves addition is recursive in our model. A similar argument proves multiplication is recursive.

---

I changed the meta-theory to be ZFC since I may need choice to prove $\mathbb{A}$ can be well ordered.

There seems to be two main objections. The first is that my proof leads to contradictions. This is an attempt to prove a contradiction to Tennebaum's theorem. If this proof is valid it can be used to prove anything including the idea that every set of natural numbers is recursive. Initially, I was trying to prove every finite set of natural numbers is recursive. This is enought to derive a contradiction. I was able to simplify the proof when I realized the set could be countable instead of finite.

The second objection is $\mathbb{A}$ is not a recursive set. This is not accurate. One can argue that addition as defined by $\mathbb{A}$ is not recursive. This is irrelevent to my argument. I make no assumptions about how $\mathbb{A}$ defines addition. I only assume $\mathbb{A}$ exists and is countable. I think the fact there is an injection from $\mathbb{A}$ to the standard natural numbers is enough for my proof to go through.

Comment: Why do you believe your bijection is recursive?  More specifically, countability doesn't per force come with a mapping to the naturals, so you can't guarantee that you can linearly iterate over the elements of $\mathbb{A}$.  In fact, the situation is almost the opposite of what you're trying to show: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum's_theorem

Comment: I trying to derive a contradiction. If a set is countable then a mapping to the naturals must exist.

Comment: You are arguing that every subset of the naturals is recursive.

Comment: Your argument shows that the graphs of the addition and multiplication functions of your model are recursive in any enumeration of the model. However, the enumeration itself does not need to be recursive (in fact, it cannot be if the model is non-standard).

Comment: I am simply using the definition of [countable set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set). A set is countable if there is a bijection with the (standard) natural numbers.

Comment: General choice-related statement. If something is countable, then it is well-orderable to begin with. And the fact that the product of two countable sets (or three, or finitely many) is countable is provable without the axiom of choice quite easily.

Comment: Your function ADD searches a non-recursive set $\mathbb A$, so there is no reason to think that it is recursive.

Comment: @Andreas: It's hard to search for a non-recursive set with ADD. But I suppose that modern availability of Ritalin helps. :-P

Comment: Russell, there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ bijections between $\Bbb A$ and $\omega$. But only $\aleph_0$ of them are possibly recursive. For each of these permutations $f$ consider the addition it defines on $\omega$, by transporting the structure of standard addition (explicitly, this is $\{\langle f(n), f(m),f(n+m)\rangle\mid n,m\in\omega\}$ as a set of ordered triplets). This defines uncountably many models of $\sf PA$, but only countably many of them are recursive models.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I only need one injection from $\mathbb{A}$ to $\aleph_0$ to be recursive.

Comment: The fact that you only need one injection doesn't mean it exists.

Comment: (It seems that your argument for proving that Tennenbaum's theorem is false is this, "Assume that Tennenbaum's theorem is false, then there is a recursive non-standard model, therefore Tennenbaum's theorem is false!". You're begging the question!)

Comment: To address one of the notes in the edit: it is in fact _correct_ that every finite set is recursive, but _not_ true that every countable set is, which is the essential point.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: It is easy to prove the model thinks the model is recursive. All that is left to prove is that the meta-theory thinks the model is recursive. I don't make any assumptions about Tennebaum's theorem. I only assume $\mathbb{A}$ is countable and the meta-theory, ZFC, is standard. This means $\aleph_0$ in the meta-theory is the standard natural numbers.

Comment: @Steve Stadnicki: If every finite set is recursive then every non-standard finite set is recursive. All non-standard finite sets being recursive is enought to derive a contradiction with Tennenbaum's theorem.

Comment: (1) Standard means, essentially, the integers of the meta-theory. You seem to have a fundamental lack of understanding about these things, and these fine and (very!) delicate points are the crux of your mistakes. (2) You wrote that your goal is to prove that Tennenbaum's theorem is in fact false, and thus arrive at a contradiction and conclude that the foundational theories of mathematics are inconsistent. But your assumption is in fact equivalent to assuming from the start that Tennenbaum's theorem is false, so you're begging the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaw is the same as in this argument:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be an infinite set of natural numbers that is not computably enumerable. Then $A$ is countably infinite; let $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to A$ be a bijection. We can enumerate $A$ as $f(0), f(1), f(2), \ldots$. This gives a procedure for enumerating $A$, so $A$ is computably enumerable, which is a contradiction.

The bijection $f$ in that argument will not be computable, and so the procedure given is not effective.  It is true that every countable set is in bijection with the natural numbers, but the bijections are rarely computable.

Comment: We can prove $\mathbb{A}$ is infinite even though we can also prove there is no computable algorithm that maps $\aleph$ to $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: @Russell Easterly: we can prove that every model of PA is infinite, so if $\mathbb{A}$ is a model of PA, yes. If $A$ is my set above, it is infinite by assumption. But, yes, the key point is that being infinite means there is *some* bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, not necessarily a computable one. If "infinite r.e." was a synonym for "infinite", we wouldn't talk about r.e. sets in the first place.